# IOS: How to use RSA public key decrypt ciper in swift?

Tags: swift, encryption, rsa, public-key

I want to use public key decrypt.But it does not work.Anyone can help me?

`discShadow_DecryptionWithRSAKey` is the delegate method where I get data coming from server.
Please find below snippet for more information. I am using RSA for encryption and decryption.

```
private class func discShadow_DecryptionWithRSAKey(encryptedData:Data,rsaKeyRef:SecKey,padding:SecPadding) -> Data? {
    let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(rsaKeyRef)

    var encryptedDataAsArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: encryptedData.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        (encryptedData as NSData).getBytes(&encryptedDataAsArray, length: encryptedData.count)

    var decryptedData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 0)
    var idx = 0
    while (idx < encryptedDataAsArray.count ) {
        var idxEnd = idx + blockSize
        if ( idxEnd > encryptedDataAsArray.count ) {
            idxEnd = encryptedDataAsArray.count
        }
        var chunkData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
        for i in idx..<idxEnd {
            chunkData[i-idx] = encryptedDataAsArray[i]
        }

        var decryptedDataBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
        var decryptedDataLength = blockSize

        let status = SecKeyDecrypt(rsaKeyRef, padding, chunkData, idxEnd-idx, &decryptedDataBuffer, &decryptedDataLength)
        if ( status != noErr ) {
            return nil
        }

        var idxFirstZero = -1
        var idxNextZero = decryptedDataBuffer.count
        for i in 0..<decryptedDataBuffer.count {
            if ( decryptedDataBuffer[i] == 0 ) {
                if ( idxFirstZero < 0 ) {
                    idxFirstZero = i
                } else {
                    idxNextZero = i
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        var newData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: idxNextZero-idxFirstZero-1)
        for i in idxFirstZero+1..<idxNextZero {
            newData[i-idxFirstZero-1] = decryptedDataBuffer[i]
        }

        decryptedData += newData

        idx += blockSize
    }

    return Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(decryptedData), count: decryptedData.count)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what exactly does not work. See also here: [ask].

Comment: You loop implies that you try to split your stream into blocks and encrypt each block with RSA. RSA is not designed to work on streams. It can be used to encrypt and decrypt the symmetric key which in turn can be used to work on streams. So usually you use public key of message recipient to encrypt new random symmetric key, encrypt message itself by symmetric algorithm and then send combination of encrypted key and encrypted message of arbitrary size to recipient. Recipient decrypts the key by its private key and uses it to decrypt the payload by using symmetric algorithm